# Вернуть значение из анонимного класса

Tags: java, android

Как можно вернуть значение с метода который использует анонимный класс,

```
String driveId;
public String search(String title) {
    driveId = "";
    Query query = new Query.Builder().addFilter(Filters.eq(SearchableField.TITLE, title)).build();
    Drive.DriveApi.query(mGoogleApiClient, query).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult metadataBufferResult) {
            if (metadataBufferResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                MetadataBuffer mdb = metadataBufferResult.getMetadataBuffer();
                for (Metadata metadata : mdb) {
                    if (metadata == null || !metadata.isDataValid() || metadata.isTrashed())
                        continue;                       
                    driveId = metadata.getDriveId().encodeToString();

                }
            }
        }
    });
    return driveId;
}
```

driveId возвращается пустой потому как он запускает в другом потоке, надо бы вернуть значение прямо из анонимного класса, как это можно сделать?

Comment: Анонимный класс тут не причём. Вас интересует возвращение асинхронного результата. Для этого надо пользоваться интерфейсом [`Future<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в <не анонимном классе>, куда нужно вернуть это значение определить метод

```
onDriveIdReceived(String driveId);
```

который вызвать из анонимного класса.

Или сделалть анонимный класс не анонимным.

Еще можно заморочиться с синхронизацией потоков, но это будет костылеговнокод.

Comment: я создал метод в не анонимном классе но не было толку, так как мне  нужно чтобы оно вернуло значение, а как можно сделать в моем случае анонимный класс не анонимным?

Comment: @YeldosTanikin, если толку нет, то вы не понимаете идею ассинхронного выполнения задач.

Comment: я пытался понять как можно использовать этот метод, вызывать я его смогу, но ведь мне нужно чтобы метод search возвращал значение.

Comment: @YeldosTanikin просто переместите "использование результата метода search()" в метод onDriveIdReceived. И вместо результата search используйте driveId

Answer (score 3):

Таким образом все равно не получится получить данные, так как как вы правильно сказали запрос к серверу осуществляется в другом потоке, и метод отрабатывается и отдает пустую строку в основном потоке быстрее, чем метод в другом потоке. Нужно организовать запрос таким образом, чтобы ваше приложение ждало пока запрос заберет из сервера данные, с помощью метода await(), и уже потом продолжит работу. Можете взглянуть реализацию [здесь](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/queries), в разделе Retrieving the result of a query.